# Loop overwrites output

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of objects and i want to serialze the objects because I want to add them in a dataframe. My problem is, when I execute the following loop, that the output is a long raw()-vector with all objects together. Its shows something like that: `[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 01 03 19 00 00 04 02 00 [33] 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 04 6d 65 74 61 00 00 02 13 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 [65] 04 00 09 00 00 00 24 49 6e 43 68 49 4b 65 79 3d 44 53 42 58 43 4d 53 44 48 51 53`

The output seems to be overwritten in each loop.

```
objects #list of objects
for (i in 1:length(objects)) {
  output <- serialize(objects[[i]],connection=NULL)
  }
output
```

I want to have each object serialize at its own and add the output in a dataframe. I have not found any solution on my specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with a `for` loop you need to initialize the `output` object before the loop starts. In the loop you use `[[i]]` so that for each `i` a new element is created in `output`

```
output <- list()
for (i in 1:length(objects)) {
  output[[i]] <- serialize(objects[[i]], connection=NULL)
}
output
```

Using `lapply()` you can simplify the code somewhat, as you don't need to initialize the `output`.

```
output <- lapply(objects, serialize, connection=NULL)
output
```